# weird behavior of nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

i constructed a nested object below:

```
var outerMost = {

    inner1: {

    innerCall: alert( "i'm the call from inner1" ),

        inner2: {

        innerCall: alert( "i'm the call from inner2" ),

            inner3: {

            innerCall: alert( "i'm the call from inner3" ),

                inner4: {

                innerCall: alert( "i'm the call from inner4" ),

                    inner5: {

                    innerCall: alert( "i'm the call from inner5" ),

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

All i want is to hear the call form inner4 by using this:

```
outerMost.inner1.inner2.inner3.inner4.innerCall();
```

But i got calls form every inner alert and was threw an error message pointing to the last expression from the debugger:

```
Property 'innerCall' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

What's wrong with my outerMost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I'm not going to keep repeating your entire object literal, I'll just use an abbreviated form...*

Each time you said this:

```
{ innerCall: alert( "i'm the call from inner1" ) }
```

You weren't creating a property `innerCall` that was the `alert()` function, you were creating a property `innerCall` that was assigned the result of actually calling the `alert()` function at that moment. The return from `alert()` is `undefined`.

So nesting that structure five levels deep called `alert()` five times all in the process of creating your object, but the actual `innerCall` properties were all set to `undefined`. So then this:

```
outerMost.inner1.inner2.inner3.inner4.innerCall();
```

Was like saying `undefined();` - which of course doesn't work.

What you need is for `innerCall` to reference a function which in turn calls `alert()`:

```
{ innerCall : function() { alert("I'm the call from inner1"); } }
```

That is more or less equivalent to doing this:

```
function myInnerCallFunction1() {
   alert("I'm the call from inner1");
}

{ innerCall : myInnerCallFunction1 }
```

(Note that in the object literal `myInnerCallFunction1` does not have parentheses so it is a reference to the function rather than executing the function.)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify that your innerCalls objects are functions... Correct code below

```
var outerMost = {

    inner1: {

    innerCall: function() {alert( "i'm the call from inner1" )},

        inner2: {

        innerCall: function() {alert( "i'm the call from inner2" )},

            inner3: {

            innerCall: function() {alert( "i'm the call from inner3" )},

                inner4: {

                innerCall: function() {alert( "i'm the call from inner4" )},

                    inner5: {

                    innerCall: function() {alert( "i'm the call from inner5" )},

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way:

```
var outerMost = {

inner1: {

    innerCall: function () {
        alert("i'm the call from inner1")
    },

    inner2: {

        innerCall: function () {
            alert("i'm the call from inner2")
        },

        inner3: {

            innerCall: function () {
                alert("i'm the call from inner3")
            },

            inner4: {

                innerCall: function () {
                    alert("i'm the call from inner4")
                },

                inner5: {

                    innerCall: function () {
                        alert("i'm the call from inner1")
                    },

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
};
outerMost.inner1.inner2.inner3.inner4.innerCall();
```